# Android Emulator Freezing on Load Screen

Tags: android, eclipse, load, emulation

I am beginning android development using the latest versions of the android SDK and eclipse. I have followed the Hello Android Tutorial
and used every combination of targets available but the Emulator freezes on the load screen with the flashing "android" title.

I have checked the other related question and DID wait about 15 minutes. but still no change. Any help with this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and still do sometimes today. Have you tried deleting the AVD and then re-creating it?

Also try changing some of the AVD's values, give it more ram, larger SD card. You can do this through Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager > Edit the AVD, and then add values / modify the SD card size.

EDIT: Also - just for reference, I have a Intel Core i7 with 16gb of RAM and AVD's STILL take forever to load.

EDIT: Another handy thing to know is that if you check the "Snapshot" option when editing the AVD, it will save the last state and load that instead of a full [slow] boot. Kind of like putting your computer to sleep.

Comment: Thanks! I reset some memory settings and that did it!

Answer (score 2):

Adding values / modify the SD card size may be better .
Try not to close the Android Emulator , to avoid  re-open .

Answer (score 0):

Yah android emulator takes time to start up, but it should start within 2-3 mins. Check your RAM and processor. The RAM must be atleast 1GB (preferably more) to speed up loading emulator.